# Python - Plotting from data file with errorbars?

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I've got a data file (data.txt) that has 6 columns:
Column 1 and 4 are the x and y data with column 2 and 3 being the (unsymmetrical) error bars for column 1 and columns 4 and 5 being the (unsymmetrical) error bars for column 6:

```
100 0.77 1.22 3   0.11 0.55
125 0.28 1.29 8   0.15 0.53
150 0.43 1.11 14  0.10 0.44
175 0.33 1.01 22  0.18 0.49
200 0.84 1.33 34  0.11 0.48
```

**What I want to plot this**. I know I need to use

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plotfile(......)

plt.show()
```

The bit in between the parenthesis in plotfile is where I'm not sure how to relate these error bars to the columns (as well as anything else I missed).

Comment: That seems like a pretty advanced case for `plotfile()`; why don't you simply read the data with `numpy.loadtxt` and plot it with `plt.errorbar`? That will only give you a few extra lines of code, and it would probably also make your code easier to read/understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `numpy.loadtxt` works perfectly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt("data.txt")
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 3]
# errorbar expects array of shape 2xN and not Nx2 (N = len(x)) for xerr and yerr
xe = data[:, 1:3].T
ye= data[:, 4:].T

plt.errorbar(x, y, xerr=xe, yerr=ye, fmt=".-")

# if you want a log plot:
plt.xscale("log")
plt.yscale("log")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Fantastic! Is there an extra line or two of code to make this a symmetric log plot? (Both x and y)? I know in this case it's not necessary considering the data but assuming a log plot is needed in future data?